# Capture command Parameter value in mvvm

Tags: wpf

I have two radio button.I just want to capture the selected radio button value in viewmodel.I have defined a  method GetLOB() in which I want to capture the commandParameter value.

Here is my code

```
<RadioButton GroupName="Os" Content="Payroll" IsChecked="{Binding ObjEntrySheetManagerViewModel.CheckedProperty}" Command="LobType" CommandParameter="Payroll" Grid.Row="4"  Grid.Column="0" Margin="25,15,0,0"/>
<RadioButton GroupName="Os" Content="Sales" Grid.Row="4"  Grid.Column="1" Command="LobType" CommandParameter="Payroll" Margin="5,15,0,0"/>


     private RelayCommand _LobType;
            public ICommand LobType
            {
                get
                {
                    if (_LobType == default(RelayCommand))
                    {
                        _LobType = new RelayCommand(GetLOB);
                    }
                    return _LobType;
                }
            }

            private void GetLOB()
            {

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Capture parameter using lambda *(assuming RelayCommand used by you have overloaded constructor which will take `Action<object>` as argument)*

```
public ICommand LobType
{
    get
    {
       if (_LobType == default(RelayCommand))
       {
          _LobType = new RelayCommand(param => GetLOB(param));
       }
       return _LobType;
    }
}

private void GetLOB(object parameter)
{

}
```

---

Relay command sample from [**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) (in case you need):

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    #region Fields

    readonly Action<object> _execute; 
    readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    { }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    { 
        if (execute == null) 
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    #endregion

    #region ICommand Members

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) 
    { 
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged 
    { 
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298910/mvvm-light-relaycommand-parameters solution.

but I was getting " The non generic type cannot be used with RelayCommand cannot be used with typed argument" error.
Any Idea about the error.